# How to allow IIFE syntax with ESlint in useCallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have the following lint error :

[image: Eslint forbid await/async]

It does `Insert ';' prettier/prettier` error, if I let my IDE fix it, I have a semicolon on the first line:

```
;(async () => {
```

It then complains about another rule being violated: `unnecessary semicolon` and offer me to remove the semicolon, etc.

How can I allow IIFE syntax in my project?

Comment: Why is there an IIFE in the first place? The `async`/`await` is useless as you're not doing anything with the `Promise`.

Comment: That's not my point, I am not looking for a code review, I just tried this and I will most likely need this synthax

Comment: It's line 2: `(async() => {})()`

Comment: Either don't use an IIFE (or async/await) or adjust the prettier and ESlint rules. Looks like it is [caused by the `no-semi` option of prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2800).

Comment: Do you mean using promise instead of async/await? Your suggestion won't help, we do not use semicolon and rules are still conflicting.

Comment: With a promise (`.then`/`.catch`), there's no possible ambiguity which Prettier is trying to fix with a semicolon, which an IIFE introduces.

Comment: Or add a simple `// eslint-disable-next-line no-extra-semi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to keep both prettier and a stylistic lint rule happy, as they are enforcing different conventions.

If you're using prettier - you need to disable stylistic lint rules.
Stylistic lint rules can and ***will*** conflict with prettier, as you've just seen.

**This is mentioned in the [prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html).**

Using [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) can help you correct your config.